# Drawing image with round corners on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to draw image with round corners. How to do this on an iPhone?

Comment: Programming language?  Framework?

Comment: I would guess Objective-C and Cocoa Touch given the tag!

Comment: I want to ask well structured question. How to do this.

Comment: The description of the image isn't so great anyhow. xD

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1):

See duplicated question **[How to mask a square image into an image with round corners in the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk)**

Answer (score 1):

i hope this may help:

[Round the corners of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142446/round-the-corners-of-an-image)

all you have to do is to:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

//Then do this. Change "theImageView" with the name of your ImageView

theImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12;

theImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a PNG with transparent background. Then simply round the corners of your image before adding them to the iPhone.