# Round the corners of an image

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is there a way of rounding the corners of an image that I placing in an imageview?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
theImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12;
```

might also need

```
theImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: This has worked for me.  Can you add some more details or a code snippet about how you are using this?  Is the image view larger than the image?

Comment: Works great for me when I #import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>