# Rounded rect with Gradient color

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, gradient, rounded-corners

I have not really done much programming with Core Graphics. And I tend to stick with QuartzCore now that it does a lot of what I need through the layer property :)

However, I have a UIView, which is currently gradient. I'd like to add rounded corners to this UIView and the layer property does not do this when I draw the gradient:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGGradientRef glossGradient;
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.95,  // Start color
                            1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.60 }; // End color

    rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
    CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
    CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMaxY(currentBounds));
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);
}
```

I am not really sure where I should be rounding in the drawRect method. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer below with a working sample. Please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked previous question postings? I read one a while back about masking UIViews. I think the same applies pretty much on all objects which use drawRect

[How to mask a square image into an image with round corners in the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk)

---

Here's what I did, and it works fine as far as I can tell.

First, I borrowed Mr [NilObject](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457/nilobject)'s code snippet from the above mentioned post.

I modified it to fit in an object (as he wrote it as a C function instead of a method)

I subclass UIView to create my own custom view. I overload initWithRect: to make my background transparent.

So basically:

> - set transparent background (in init), or clipping will be uggly
> - in drawRect, first clip, then draw inside the clipped area

The following is a working example:

```
//
//  TeleView.m
//

#import "TeleView.h"


@implementation TeleView
/**** in init methods, set background to transparent,
      otherwise, clipping shows a black background ****/

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.0f]];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) clipCornersToOvalWidth:(float)ovalWidth height:(float)ovalHeight
{
    float fw, fh;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        return;
    }
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    /**** here is what I modified. ****/
    [self clipCornersToOvalWidth:20.0f height:20.0f];
    CGContextClip(currentContext);

    /**** below this is your own code ****/
    CGGradientRef glossGradient;
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.60,  // Start color
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.40 }; // End color

    rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
    CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
    CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMaxY(currentBounds));
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace); 

}

@end
```

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this one before. I just can't merge it with my own code :(

Comment: What happens when you try then? What do you see? Any errors? How have you tried to integrate ir?

Comment: It's either or.. If I round the corners I cannot use the gradient code, and vice versa. I am sure I am merging the two incorrectly, but CG isn't really something I have much experience with.

Comment: I'll have a look at it later today, if I can. I'll post what I can come up with.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fromColor.CGColor,toColor.CGColor, nil];

NSNumber *stopOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
NSNumber *stopTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stopOne, stopTwo, nil];

CAGradientLayer *headerLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
headerLayer.colors = colors;
headerLayer.locations = locations;

headerLayer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor; // border line color**strong text**
headerLayer.borderWidth = width;// For Thickness of border line
headerLayer.cornerRadius = radius;//For Rounded Corner if You want to make rounded Corner

headerLayer.frame = frame;

[view.layer  insertSublayer:headerLayer atIndex:0];
```

Also make sure to import "QuartzCore" framework