# Turn square image into round rect button with shine [Objective C]

Tags: objective-c, graphics, image-manipulation, effects, rounded-corners

In this picture you will see several TV show images that have been put into a rounded rect button with the same gloss/shine that an iphone app button usually has.

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img16/3020/tvforecast.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img16/3020/tvforecast.png)

In one of the icons you even see a ribbon saying "On air".

I'm wondering; how do you replicate this effect?

My guess is the programmer masked an image on top of the square image.

I'm aware that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk) covers turning square images into rounded ones.

However, how do you add the shine; and how would you add the ribbon?

In terms of memory management, is it better to create a new image that has the contents of an image + gloss + ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a mask.  This blog post has a PNG or PSD that you could adapt

http://surgeworksmobile.com/iphone/iphone-icons-how-to-preview-the-glossy-effect

You could apply the mask with ImageMagick.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/channels/#masking

If you need to do it on the phone, you'd have to link to a static lib version of ImageMagick or try to figure out how to mask it with CoreImage.