# How to set round corners in UI images in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to develop an iPhone application to set the UI Image.

Answer (score 4):

You could not set the corner of `UIImage` instance because it's not inherited from `UIView`,
So you need to create an `UIImageView` instance by passing your `UIImage`.

use the below code.

```
UIImageView * roundedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.jpg"]];
// Get the Layer of any view
CALayer * l = [roundedView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

Comment: i need set image to buttons so how to set round corners to image

Comment: @ user674490: Then set the corner of your UIButton not image. Then use CALayer * l = [myButton layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];

Answer (score 1):

use below code.

```
CALayer * l = [camBtn layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the layer of camBtn.

Setimage to that layer.

Add cornerradious  to that layer.

The camBtn should be custombutton

[//layer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752667/how-to-set-round-corners-in-ui-images-in-iphone)

```
UIImageView * roundedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.jpg"]];
// Get the Layer of any view
CALayer * l = [roundedView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cornerRadius` property

```
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;  //change value for your need
```

Answer (score 0):

set the proper radius value for this: UIImageView -> layer -> cornerRadius

Be sure to include QuartzCore.h

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
```

Where image is the image you wish to show. Display the above imageView to get the rounded effect

Comment: iam set the image to button so i need image should be rounded corners not a UI ImageView

Comment: Then make a UIButton of UIButtonTypeCustom and set the above as the background image using the setBackgroundImage message

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: ...];
pic.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
pic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need QuartzCore framework for this.

- Import QuartzCore Framwork
- Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> to your .h` file

then use

```
UIImageView *imgViw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
imgViw.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
imgViw.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;//For border
```