# How to make UIImage rounded,Not rounded corner

Tags: uiimageview, draw, geometry

Draw a circle,make a rounded UIImageView in it.How to get this, please guide me. 
thx!

Comment: It's not clear to me. You want a ImageView like this?

http://www.interiordesign.net/photo/348/348655-Theater_in_the_Round.jpg

Comment: yes,and the circle's border is white color.

Comment: Is the circle radius always fixed?.

Comment: yes,circle radius always fixed,but in circle,imageview maybe change

Comment: This may not work for you but worth a try. 

1. Create two ImageViews. 

2. One for your image which you wanna display.

3. Over the previous ImageView another one with an image of a white  circle border, adding transparency only to the area which you wanna display your previous image.

Hope this will help. Tell me if it is not clear.

Comment: if display imageview larger than white circle border one.how can i display it.two imageview's rect is the same?

Comment: The one with the white circle should be an ImageView size of the screen so that your displaying image won't be visible other than the circle. Clear enough?.

Comment: Here is an example made for you

ImageView 2: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/3431/test2sn.png

Final Image: http://imageshack.us/f/580/testjkn.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's put it this way,

- First we create a UIImageView to the size of the circle you want.Let's say you want this image to be a circular image,

> http://united4iran.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/cell-phone-in-canada.jpg

- Then you create another UIImageView one top of the previous one to the size of 320x480 and set [this](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/3431/test2sn.png) image to it (Assume this image size is 320x480),

Note: also remember that inner area of the circle in above image is transparent.

- Then you should get a image like this,

> http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/782/testjkn.png

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks a lot first!but it unuseful for me.below the display imageview also has a imageview,outer area of circle imageview must transparent.So display imageview full rect visible.Do you know about context?

Comment: Try this one,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: finally,i decide that use context to cut the image and above it put a    circle imageview.thankyou for guide me.