# How to mask WKInterfaceImage programmatically

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, quartz-core

I used to use the following code to mask `UIImageView` in iOS

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

profilePhoto.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = profilePhoto.bounds.size.width/2;
```

and here is the result:

Any one know how to do the same for `WKInterfaceImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Core Graphics to draw your image masked to a circle and then set that image to WKInterfaceImage.  See this post for how to draw an image with a circle map using Core Graphics.  [How to mask a square image into an image with round corners in the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk)

Here is the code copied from the other SO post and modified just a little to get the image clipped to a circle out.  (I haven't run this code, so there may be a few issues with it.  It should get you close.)

```
static void addRoundedRectToPath(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, float ovalWidth, float ovalHeight)
{
    float fw, fh;
    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        return;
    }
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

UIImage* img = <My_Image_To_Draw?
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, NO, 2.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width, img.size.height);
addRoundedRectToPath(context, rect, img.size.width, img.size.height);
CGContextClip(context);
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIImage* imageClippedToCircle = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

//Now you can use imageClippedToCircle
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate with a piece of code as I still can not map the code in the answer to the watch kit

Comment: Thanks @Stephen it works, I just had to modify the call to `addRoundedRectToPath(context, rect, img.size.width/2.0, img.size.height/2.0);` to have clip the photo in a circle